# How to increase speed of my Spark application while doing some element wise operation

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, iterator

I am using Spark and running experiments on Cluster but my application is taking too much time. When I try to find issue I found it inside **mapPartitionsWithIndex**. Here is explanation.

I have created class

```
class demo ( dim:Int  ,  min:Double  ,  max:Double    ) extends Serializable  {
 val random = new Random()
 var position      : Array[Double]       =   Array.fill  (  dim  )(  random.nextDouble ( ) *  ( max - min  ) + min  )
 var velocity      : Array[Double]       =   Array.fill  (  dim  )(  math.random  )
 var PulseRate     : Double              =   0.1
 var LoudnessRate  : Double              =   0.95
 var frequency     : Double              =   math.random
 var fitness       : Double              =   math.random//function (  position.toList ,0  )
 var newFitness    : Double              =   math.random// function (  position.toList ,0  )
 var newPosition   : Array[Double]       =   Array.fill  (  dim  )  (  math.random  )
}
```

and Inside main function I created RDD as following.

```
 val N = 1000    // could be up to 3000
 val d = 1000    // could be up to 3000
 val Min = -600
 val iterations = 10000000  // could be up to 1 Billion
 val Max = 600
 val totalPartitions = 4 // could be up to 30
 val myList = List.fill(N)(new demo(d, Min, Max))
 val myRDD = scc.parallelize  (  myList ,totalPartitions  ) //create RDD
 myRDD.persist( StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK )
 RDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex {
  (  index  ,  Iterator  )  =>  {
    var li  =  Iterator.toList
    for (i <- 1 to iterations) {
     val Best = li.minBy(_.fitness).position
     li.map { j =>
          j.frequency = Fmin + ( Fmax - Fmin ) * math.random  ;
          j.velocity  = (  j.position, Best  ) .zipped.map  (  _  -  _ ).map  ( _ * j.frequency ), j.velocity  ).zipped.map(  _  +  _ )
        }
    }
    li.take(5).toIterator
   }
  }
```

So I found that portion of code

```
j.velocity  = (  j.position, Best  ) .zipped.map  (  _  -  _ ).map  ( _ * j.frequency ), j.velocity  ).zipped.map(  _  +  _ )
```

is slowing performance where I have to do element wise operation of Lists. All other things are fine but it takes too much time to complete execution. How can I improve my Performance? I have to boost only this portion where Element wise operation are performed.

Comment: A bit off-topic but, **parallelism** + **concurrency** + **mutability** = _disaster_. I would recommend you to refactor your code to use `case classes` and other immutable data structures.

Comment: Also, instead of creating a local _big_ **List** and then parallelize it. Consider using `spark.range(N).map(_ => new demo(d, Min, Max))`. - PS: Also, you may consider follow the [**Scala** _style guidelinnes_](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/) it would make your code easier to read.

Comment: May I ask why do all those iterations inside the `mapPartitions` instead of doing N recursive maps over the **RDD**? Why at the end you return just the first five elements of the List? Also are you sure that you really want to do that process for each partition, wouldn't that give you partial results between the partitions?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes I want to do for each partition. At end I need I need five best elements based on their fitness (i do not added here to sort and take five). For N iteration I have to iterate inside mapPartition based on per Partition.